# not getting the desired output in html file

Tags: python, web.py

i am trying to make a branch predictor:

this is the code that i have in app.py:

```
import web
urls = (
'/hello','index'
)

app = web.application(urls,globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')

class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form=web.input(name='nobody', rank=0)
        branch=None
        if form.rank<=4613:
            branch = 'COE, ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
        if int(form.rank)<=7471 & int(form.rank)>4613:
            branch='ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
        if int(form.rank)<=11325 & int(form.rank)>7471:
            branch = 'IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
        if int(form.rank)<=16565 & int(form.rank)>11325:
            branch='ICE,MPAE,BT'
        if int(form.rank)<=17955 & int(form.rank)>16565:
            branch='MPAE,BT'
        if int(form.rank)<=20714 & int(form.rank)<17955:
            branch='BT'
        return render.index(branch=branch) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

this is the code that i have in my html file hello_form.html

```
<h1>NSIt Branch Predictor for First Round</h1>
<form action='hello' method ='POST'>
Your Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'name'>
<br>
AIEEE Rank: <input type = 'text' name ='rank'>
<input type='submit'>
```

This is the code that i have in the index.html:

```
$def with (branch)
branch: $branch
```

and i have the layout.html as follows:

```
$def with (content)
<html>
<head>
<title> first python website</title>
</head>
<body>
$:content
</body>
</html>
```

but in the output i am getting :

```
branch:
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the application framework that you are using, but there are numerous problems in your `POST` method.  Here is what it should probably look like.  Then I'll talk about the problems and some alternative solutions.

```
def POST(self):
    form = web.input(name='nobody', rank='0')
    rank = int(form.rank)
    if rank <= 4613:
        branch = 'COE, ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
    elif rank <= 7471:
        branch = 'ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
    elif rank <= 11325:
        branch = 'IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
    elif rank <= 16565:
        branch = 'ICE,MPAE,BT'
    elif rank <= 17955:
        branch = 'MPAE,BT'
    elif rank <= 20714:
        branch = 'BT'
    else:
        branch = None
    return render.index(branch=branch)
```

The first problem is that your first comparison was between a string and an integer: `if form.rank<=4613`.  That should have been `if int(form.rank)<=4613`.  Comparing strings and numbers rarely does what you would expect.

```
>>> rank = '4613'
>>> rank <= 4613
False
>>> rank > sys.maxint
True
```

Next, you were using the [bitwise and operator `&`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) instead of the [boolean `and` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).  For example, `int(form.rank)<=7471 & int(form.rank)>4613` should have been `int(form.rank)<=7471 and int(form.rank)>4613`.

You could have improved this by using [operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in) instead of the `and` stuff:

```
if rank <= 4613:
    branch = 'COE, ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
if 4613 < rank <= 7471:
    branch = 'ECE,IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
if 7471 < rank <= 11325:
    branch = 'IT,ICE,MPAE,BT'
```

Ultimately, what you had is best represented as a chain of `if` and `elif` statements unless you want to use an interval based data structure of some sort.  For something this simple, the `if` statements work fine.

Happy Pythoning!